# Including material widget without inheriting from scaffold or

Tags: flutter

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: TextSubmitToProvider()));
}

class TextSubmitToProvider extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.multitrack_audio_rounded),
        onPressed: () {
          print("hello");
        });
  }
}
```

For the above code I get the error:

> IconButton widgets require a Material widget ancestor. ... (explantion about why
> i need a material widget in the tree above...)

Ok. I get the reason why i need to have a material ancestor in my widget tree,
but what confuses me is the next part of the error message
that says:

> "To introduce a Material widget, you can either directly include one,
> or use a widget that contains Material itself, such as a Card, Dialog, Drawer,
> or Scaffold."

The part that is throwing me off is the "or" part
which seems to imply i have two options:

(1) Directly include a material widget.

(2) Include a widget that contains material itself.

The second option i get (this is what i am currently doing in my app), but
what i dont understand is the first option.

What does it mean to directly include a material widget? I initially interpreted
this to mean i can directly inherit from MaterialApp(), but I dont think this is
a correct interpretation since i am inheriting from MaterialApp() in this example.

So my question is this: What does it mean to "directly include a Material Widget"?

I know all the answers say to just inherit from Scaffold, but this seems a bit
unnecessary since i am not actually using anything to do with the scaffold widget.
I am just using it to bootstrap Material into my app. Is there a cleaner way of
doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1:**
You can wrap the Icon with The material Widget (Directly Including a material Widget)

```
class TextSubmitToProvider extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.multitrack_audio_rounded),
          onPressed: () {
            print("hello");
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

**Q:2** Including a widget that contains material itself means that you can use the card, scaffold, etc which contains the `Material()`

if you open the dart file for card (card.dart) you can see that the container is wrapped with a `Material` widget.

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The Material() widget was the obvious thing i was missing.